# How do I tell java to stop the loop at a certain character in a string?

Tags: java

So if i have a method where a string is entered and has a hyphen. like "cool*boy" if i want java to make a new string that starts out at the end of that string and prints each letter backward and continues until it reaches the asterisk and then goes forward and prints all the letters after the asterisk again so in the cool*boy example it's "yobboy" or high*school would be "loohcsschool" ... how would I do this. Thank you.

to JUST get everything up to the asterisk sign (which isn't working) I put,

```
int i;
String newStr = "";
for(i=s.length()-1; i >= s.charAt('*'); i--)
     newStr = newStr + s.charAt(i);
```

I'm guessing you're not allowed to make that condition in the for loop. But I just don't get how you would do it. Please help thanks!

Comment: `if (some condition is true) break;`

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Just saying...

Comment: (And, actually, you can put any test you want in the second control expression of the `for` loop, and the test can be as complex as you want, with dozens of different tests combined with `&&` and `||`, if you wish.)

Comment: You can try parsing...String phrase = "the music made   it   hard      to        concentrate";
String delims = "[a]+";
String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
then do an if(tokens[i]){break}

Comment: Jacob At Work, this is a practice problem for final exam.

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition to

```
s.charAt(i) != '*'
```

Comment: If you do this, shouldn't you also ensure that i doesn't drop below 0? There's no guarantee a * is in the string. i.e. `s.charAt(i) != '*' &&  i >= 0`

Comment: Good point, that would have been another exercise for the OP. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a substring instead of a loop.

```
String forward = s.substring(s.indexOf('*')+1);
String reverse = new StringBuilder(forward).reverse().toString();
return reverse+forward;
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested codes:

```
String s = "high*school";

    String newString = "";
    String[] arr = s.split("[*]");
    if (arr.length == 2) {
        newString = new StringBuilder(arr[1]).reverse().toString() + arr[1];
    }else{
       ... if the string has no (or more than one) "*"...
        handle it if it is reqired.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Apache Commons StringUtils library:

```
substringBefore(String str, String separator)

substringAfter(String str,  String separator)

reverse(String str)
```

Link: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html